# Show sum of grouped column in new row for each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I want to show sum of data after each group in the sql result set.

I have two table Group 1

```
-------------------------------------
Group       Name        Sale
-------------------------------------
G1          ABC1        10
.....................................
G1          ABC2        20
.....................................
G1          ABC3        40
```

and Group 2

```
-------------------------------------
Group       Name        Sale
.....................................
G2          XYZ1        34
.....................................
G2          XYZ2        14
.....................................
G2          XYZ3        44
```

I want to show data like below :

```
-------------------------------------
Group       Name        Sale
-------------------------------------
G1          ABC1        10
.....................................
G2          XYZ1        34
.....................................
TOTAL       TOTAL       44                -- Calculated Row
.....................................
G1          ABC2        20
.....................................
G2          XYZ2        14
.....................................
TOTAL       TOTAL       34                -- Calculated Row
.....................................
G1          ABC3        40
.....................................
G2          XYZ3        44
.....................................
TOTAL       TOTAL       84                -- Calculated Row
.....................................
```

is this possible ?

Comment: You need to know how match the rows from 1st group to those from 2nd group. Then you could do some `UNION`s to achieve your result. Would probably result in some ugly SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some assumptions here. Namely that the "Name" is always 4 characters and if it ends in "1" then it is related to the Name from the other table that also ends in "1". You can see this in the the LEFT OUTER JOIN in the last unionized SELECT statement in the derived UnionTotal table.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Substring(name, 4, 1) as sortOrder,
            Group,
            Name,
            Sale
        FROM Group1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            Substring(Name, 4, 1) as sortOrder,
            Group,
            Name,
            Sale
        FROM Group2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            Substring(G1.Name, 4, 1) as sortOrder,
            "Total" as Group,
            "Total" as Name,
            G1.Sale + G2.Sale as Sale
        FROM
            Group1 as G1
            LEFT OUTER JOIN Group2 as G2 ON
                Substring(G1.Name, 4, 1) = Substring(G2.Name, 4, 1)

    ) as unionTotal
ORDER BY sortOrder, Group;
```